# Array.Find and IndexOf for multiple elements that are exactly the same object

Tags: arrays, powershell, indexing

I have trouble of getting index of the current element for multiple elements that are exactly the same object:

```
$b = "A","D","B","D","C","E","D","F"
$b | ? { $_ -contains "D" }
```

Alternative version:

```
$b = "A","D","B","D","C","E","D","F"
[Array]::FindAll($b, [Predicate[String]]{ $args[0] -contains "D" })
```

This will return:
D
D
D

But this code:

```
$b | % { $b.IndexOf("D") }
```

Alternative version:

```
[Array]::FindAll($b, [Predicate[String]]{ $args[0] -contains "D" }) | % { $b.IndexOf($_) }
```

Returns:

1
1
1

so it's pointing at the index of the first element. **How to get indexes of the other elements?**

Comment: if nobody comes up with a better solution you could just use a for loop, match inside it and get your index from the counter variable

Comment: @Paul That is exactly what I wanted to avoid :P

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$b = "A","D","B","D","C","E","D","F" 

(0..($b.Count-1)) | where {$b[$_] -eq 'D'}

1
3
6
```

Comment: i like it, nice and short. only thing that bugs me is the redundant pair of parenthesis (`0..($b.count-1) | `) will do it too

Comment: Attempting to use the static methods of `[array]` do not have the simplicity that this does. @Paul never hurt anyone to be explicit.

Comment: mjolinor Thank you
@Matt Besides that this answer is really nice, do you know how to do this by using methods?

Comment: @ALIENQuake This is answer needs to loop as well but is far more elegant. I posted an answer using an `[array]` method but only because you asked.

Comment: @Matt May I propose a lite improvement? Instead of ($b.count-1) we can use [array]::LastIndexOf($b,"D") - it will save us some time when we would searching 100k array and the lat element will be at 1001 or so.

Answer (score 6):

[mjolinor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27691180/45375) is **conceptually elegant**, but **slow with large arrays**, presumably due to having to build a parallel array of indices first (which is also memory-inefficient).

It is conceptually similar to the following **LINQ-based solution** (PSv3+), which is more memory-efficient and **about twice as fast, but still slow**:

```
$arr = 'A','D','B','D','C','E','D','F'
[Linq.Enumerable]::Where(
 [Linq.Enumerable]::Range(0, $arr.Length), 
   [Func[int, bool]] { param($i) $arr[$i] -eq 'D' }
)
```

While any **PowerShell looping** solution is ultimately slow compared to a compiled language, the following alternative, while **more verbose**, is still **much faster with large arrays**:

```
PS C:\> & { param($arr, $val)
         $i = 0
         foreach ($el in $arr) { if ($el -eq $val) { $i } ++$i }
        } ('A','D','B','D','C','E','D','F') 'D'
1
3
6
```

Note:

- Perhaps surprisingly, this solution is even faster than [Matt's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27693403/45375), which calls `[array]::IndexOf()` in a loop instead of enumerating *all* elements.
- Use of a script block (invoked with call operator `&` and arguments), while not strictly necessary, is used to prevent polluting the enclosing scope with helper variable `$i`.
- The `foreach` *statement* is faster than the `Foreach-Object` *cmdlet* (whose built-in aliases are `%` and, confusingly, also `foreach`).
- Simply (implicitly) outputting `$i` for each match makes PowerShell collect multiple results in an array.

  - If only *one* index is found, you'll get a scalar `[int]` instance instead; wrap the whole command in `@(...)` to ensure that you always get an array.
- While `$i` by itself outputs the value of `$i`, `++$i` by design does NOT (though you could use `(++$i)` to achieve that, if needed).
- Unlike `Array.IndexOf()`, PowerShell's `-eq` operator is case-*insensitive* by default; for case-sensitivity, use `-ceq` instead.

---

It's easy to turn the above into a (simple) **function** (note that the parameters are purposely untyped, for flexibility):

```
function get-IndicesOf($Array, $Value) {
  $i = 0
  foreach ($el in $Array) { 
    if ($el -eq $Value) { $i } 
    ++$i
  }
}
```

```
# Sample call
PS C:\> get-IndicesOf ('A','D','B','D','C','E','D','F') 'D'
1
3
6
```

Answer (score 2):

You would still need to loop with the static methods from `[array]` but if you are still curious something like this would work.

```
$b = "A","D","B","D","C","E","D","F"
$results = @()
$singleIndex = -1
Do{
    $singleIndex = [array]::IndexOf($b,"D",$singleIndex + 1)
    If($singleIndex -ge 0){$results += $singleIndex}
}While($singleIndex -ge 0)
$results

1
3
6
```

Loop until a match is not found. Assume the match at first by assigning the `$singleIndex` to -1 ( Which is what a non match would return). When a match is found add the index to a results array.

Comment: Also good how running `[array]::IndexOf` shows all the method available as well.

Comment: @RoadRunner to be specific it would show all the available overloads for that particular static method. If you wanted to see all the static methods you could do `[array] | Get-Member -Static`